# python: what is wrong with my date index?

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe that uses dates as index. Although I can read the index values from series.index, I fail to get the corresponding record.

```py
series = pd.DataFrame([[datetime.date(2019,1,1), 'A', 4], [datetime.date(2019,1,2), 'B', 6]], columns = ('Date', 'Index', 'Value'))
series2 = series.pivot(index='Date', columns='Index', values='Value')
index = series2.index[0]
```

This far, everything works.
But this line of code fails:

```py
row = series[index]
```

The error message is

```py
KeyError: datetime.date(2019, 1, 1)
```

Why does it fail, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html) for selecting, but in `series2`, because in `series` is `RangeIndex`, not dates:

```
row = series2.loc[index]
print (row)
Index
A    4.0
B    NaN
Name: 2019-01-01, dtype: float64
```

**Details**:

```
print (series)
         Date Index  Value
0  2019-01-01     A      4
1  2019-01-02     B      6

print (series.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)

print (series2)
Index         A    B
Date                
2019-01-01  4.0  NaN
2019-01-02  NaN  6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this part after your three lines:
`series.set_index('Date', inplace=True)`

So, the whole thing is:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

series = pd.DataFrame([[datetime.date(2019,1,1), 'A', 4], 
    [datetime.date(2019,1,2), 'B', 6]], 
    columns = ('Date', 'Index', 'Value'))
series2 = series.pivot(index='Date', columns='Index', 
    values='Value')
index = series2.index[0]
series.set_index('Date', inplace=True) # this part was added
series.loc[index]
```

```
Out[57]: 
Index    A
Value    4
Name: 2019-01-01, dtype: object
```

Comment: in my case set_index was not needed, loc was sufficient. Tanks for jumping in, though!